# MLE of mixing parameters for "n" single-variable Gaussian distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, mixing

I am looking to derive the maximum likelihood estimator of the mixing parameters for "n" single-variable Gaussian distributions.

The complete model density is:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k f_k(x)
$$

where $f_k$ is the normal distribution with mean $\mu_k$ and variance $\sigma_k^2$.

The data likelihood is:

$$
L(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_m,\sigma_1^2,\dots,\sigma_m^2,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k) = \prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^m f_k^{u_{ik}}(x_i)\lambda_k^{u_{ik}}
$$

where $u_{ik}$ is an indicator variable of whether the *"i-th"* data point came from the *"k-th"* distribution.

So far, I have derived the MLEs of $\mu_k$ and $\sigma_k^2$, but when I try to calculate the MLE of $\lambda_k$, I get an incorrect result.

First, I calculate the log-likelihood:

$$
log(L) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^m u_{ik}log(f_k(x_i)) + u_{ik}log(\lambda_k)
$$

Then, I fix a particular *"k"* and calculate the derivative:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d\lambda_k} log(L_k) &= \frac{d}{d\lambda_k} \sum_{i=1}^nu_{ik}log(f_k(x_i)) + u_{ik}log(\lambda_k) \\
&= \frac{d}{d\lambda_k}\sum_{i=1}^n  u_{ik}log(\lambda_k) \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda_k}\sum_{i=1}^n  u_{ik} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Clearly, if I set this derivative equal to zero, I get no viable MLE, which I know is wrong. What is the correct way to derive the MLE?

Comment: The log likelihood isn’t continuous, so in addition to checking critical points you also need to check points of discontinuity. Said another way, your calculation of the derivatives of the indicator variables is incorrect, because they are not constant.

Comment: I know that the correct answer is $\lambda_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n u_{ik}$. How would I show this?